# Diferença entre AJAX Síncrono e POST/GET

Tags: javascript, ajax

Existe alguma diferença de performance e de funcionamento entre um **AJAX Síncrono** e uma conexão **POST/GET**? Ambos travam a *thread* (o navegador congela) mas existe outros diferenciais entre os tipos de conexões?

Comment: "uma conexão POST/GET" você quer dizer uma requisição normal do navegador com um link ou formulário?

Comment: @Sanção sim estes dois tipos de conexão do navegador

Comment: É o mesmo tipo de conexão, protocolo HTTP. Ajax síncrono não é recomendável.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ajax e Protocolo Http(Get, Post)**

O ajax é uma forma de comunicação entre cliente server que utiliza alguns tipos de protocolo. Entre esses estão o Http que utiliza oe métodos post e get para trafegar informações entre cliente e servidor. A idéia do ajax surgiu da necessidade de efetuar um comunicação com o lado servidor sem a necessidade de carregar a página novamente. Antes disso só era possível efetuar essa comunicação através de um get ou post. Era comum o uso de iframes para tal comunicação. Com a implementação do ajax foi possível dar mais dinamismo as páginas web. Foi uma grande evolução para a época(não me lembro o ano exatamente) e até hoje é amplamente utilizado.

**Performance Http(iframe) e Ajax**

Sobre a questão de performance, o ajax tem a vantagem de trafegar somente as informações pertinentes a solicitação. Ex.: Em um consulta de cliente o lado server pode implementar uma api *restfull* e retornar somente o json relacionado a esse cliente. Já na utilização de um iframe seria necessário além dos dados relacionados ao cliente trazer possíveis arquivos de js e css que estivessem relacionados a página em questão. Observe que o ajax retorna exatamente o que você quer.

**Ajax síncrono e assíncrono**

A diferença entre ambas é simples. O ajax síncrono como o próprio nome já diz aguarda o retorno da chamada para dar prosseguimento ao programa. O que isso quer dizer? O teu browser vai ficar esperando a chamada ser finalizada para dar prosseguimento a rotina que está executando. E ai que acontece o dito "IE parou de funcionar".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Particularmente evito utilizar a consulta de forma síncrona para evitar esse tipo de problema. Já o ajax assíncrono trabalha de forma a não efetuar o *lock* da rotina em questão até o retorno da chamada. É comum utilizar em um método que efetua essa consulta um parâmetro que chamamos de callback. Esse parametro indica uma função a ser executada ao termino da consulta. Dessa forma evitamos o travamento do browser.

Exemplo chamadas:

```
function init(){
    var dataSync = callAjaxSync();
    console.log(dataSync);

    callAjaxAsync(function(dataAsync){
        console.log(dataAsync);
    }, function (errorAsync) {
        console.error(errorAsync);
    });
}

function callAjaxSync(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', '/bar/foo.txt', false);
    request.send(null);
    return request.responseText;
}

function callAjaxAsync(callback, onError){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', '/bar/foo.txt', true);
    request.send(null);
    request.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200) {
                callback(request.responseText);
            } else {
                onError(request.statusText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Emir, fiquei curioso quanto a uma coisa, no método `callAjaxAsync` você não deveria ter feito uso do evento `readystatechange` e ter chamado o `callback` dentro dele quando a seguinte condição for satisfeita: `request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200`?

Comment: @TobyMosque poderia ter feito sim. Mais para fins de tornar o exemplo mais enxuto possível não usei. Mais na prática precisa ser usado sim. Isso é algo que passa despercebido por muita gente já que frameworks como jquery abstraem esse tratamento. Mais como falei se não usar um framework o correto é efetuar o tratamento

Comment: Emir, a questão que o exemplo precisa esta correto, o seu na pratica vai sempre retornar `nulo`.

Comment: @TobyMosque, certo esse detalhe passou despercebido. Já efetuei o ajuste

Comment: Emir, corrigi o seu exemplo, agora está ajustado.